# Get children from View

Tags: android

I have View. How to get and edit children inside View.

```
View myTable = inflater.inflate(R.layout.letters_table, container);

// Get and edit myTable children
```

Comment: your view is really a table?

Answer (score 3):

Not all `View`s have children. Only `ViewGroup` instances have. If you want to get the children of an inflated `View` try this:

```
if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
  ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
  for(int i = 0; i< viewGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    // Edit the child
  }
}
```